# No Captcha API responses explanation

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am testing the new Google no captcha reCaptcha and i want to clear something out.

So far using it i got the following responses:

1) Green check mark
2) Classic recaptcha and then Green Check mark(provided that you answered correctly)

Going to Google's documentation i see that the response is either true or false:

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "error-codes": [...]   // optional
}
```

Does it mean that:

TRUE == Green Check Mark

FALSE == Classic recaptcha

Or it means that:

TRUE == Green Check Mark or Classic recaptcha

FALSE ==  You are a bot

Because i have never came up against a response different than the responses i mention at the top.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my own experiment, it means that

TRUE == Green Check Mark or Classic recaptcha

FALSE == You are a bot